# Tell ScrollBars of ScrollPane not to cover content of ScrollPane

Tags: listview, javafx, scrollbar, scrollpane

How do you tell a ScrollPane, that it's ScrollBars shall not cover the content of the ScrollPane?

I tried to put a horizontal ListView into a ScrollPane, so that I can add additional ListView Items or remove them and having a ScrollBar in case they are too many to be displayed in the available space. However, whenever that happens, the ScrollPane displays ScrollBars, which cover the ListView. So in case there is not enough space, JavaFX reduces the space even more, by displaying the ScrollBars this way.

How do I fix this behavior?
Or can I dynamically change the height of the content of the ScrollPane? (I am only adding Strings to the ListView)

Ultimately, I want to achieve something like the list of tags here on stackoverflow, where you can add tags and remove them. However, I don't want a user to be confused which separator character to use and want to use add and remove buttons.

Here is what I tried:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
ObservableList<String> translations = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
translations.add("100dsfsd");
translations.add("200saf");
translations.add("300w5346");
translations.add("400ztkzu");
translations.add("500a3244tgs");
translations.add("600a324");
translations.add("4tgsarawt");
translations.add("4tgsarawt");
translations.add("4tgsarawt");
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.setItems(translations);
listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
listView.setPrefHeight(30);
scrollPane.setContent(listView);
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(30);
scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(200);
scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
```

And this is how it looks :(

http://s14.directupload.net/images/140731/j3y6s3pw.png
(Can't post images yet, because of reputation)

Or is there maybe a more appropriate Control to achieve this?

Comment: Why dont you use a `PrefHeight` property on the `scrollPane` ?

Comment: I sort of thought, that the viewport size is the size of what is in the scrollpane, which can be smaller than the size of the scrollpane itself, but it could be that I mixed something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` already comes with scrollbars as they are needed; you have no need to put a `ListView` in a `ScrollPane`.

The problem is that you are constraining the height of the `ListView` by setting its `prefHeight` property. This height includes the height of the scrollbar. Instead of setting the `prefHeight`, set the `maxHeight` to a value which is large enough to hold both the content and the scrollbar, if present.

Also make sure you are using a layout container that will allow it to grow vertically.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HorizListViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> translations = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        translations.add("100dsfsd");
        translations.add("200saf");
        translations.add("300w5346");
        translations.add("400ztkzu");
        translations.add("500a3244tgs");
        translations.add("600a324");
        translations.add("4tgsarawt");
        translations.add("4tgsarawt");
        translations.add("4tgsarawt");
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setItems(translations);
        listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        listView.setMaxHeight(50);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(new Label("Some content here"));
        root.setBottom(listView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ScrollBar` is still covering space which is previously used by the items in the `ListView`, but at least it's not covering the text anymore : ) Thanks! I think my understanding of the preferred size was a little bit wrong.